# VBA excel macro skips last column

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I have to create a csv from an excel table (range). It is not a solution to just save it as a csv file because my application needs the csv with quotations set at each cell.  The range of my table is A1:P9998 where A1:P1 is the row with the headers.

I have the following code to do the job:

```
Dim DstFileName As String, DstPfad As String
     Dim Delimiter As String
     Dim strZe As String
     Dim lRow As Long, lCol As Integer
     Dim Ze As Long, Sp As Integer
     Dim ff As Integer
   
     On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
   
     Range("A1").Select
   
     DstPfad = "C:\Temp\" 'Anpassen, muss bereits existieren
     DstFileName = DstPfad & "LCMPartnerImport.csv" 'Anpassen
     Delimiter = ","
     With ActiveSheet
     lRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
     lCol = .Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
     ff = FreeFile
     Open DstFileName For Output As #ff
     'Zeile für Zeile lesen und schreiben ...
     For Ze = 1 To lRow
     For Sp = 1 To lCol - 1
         strZe = strZe & Chr(34) & .Cells(Ze, Sp) & Chr(34) & Delimiter
         Next Sp
     strZe = strZe & .Cells(Ze, Sp)
     Print #ff, strZe
     strZe = ""
     Next Ze
   
     End With
```

This does not work properly, the complete column P has no quotations and I cannot find out why.
Does someone here have any idea to help me out?
Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0):

When using a delimiter I like this pattern:

```vb
Dim sep
'...
For Ze = 1 To lRow
     sep = ""
     strZe = ""
     For Sp = 1 To lCol
         strZe = strZe & sep & Chr(34) & .Cells(Ze, Sp) & Chr(34)
         sep = Delimiter
     Next Sp
     Print #ff, strZe
Next Ze
```

Comment: WOW, thanks Tim this helped and the csv file looks good to me now... !!!